# TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm copying the code directly as is from "Pure React" by Dave Ceddia. I'm working on the github-file-list project.

```
const FileListItem = ({ file }) => (
    <tr className="file-list-item">
        <FileName file={file} />
        <CommitMessage
            commit={file.lastestCommit} />
    </tr>
);
FileListItem.propTypes = {
    file: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const CommitMessage = ({ commit }) => (
    <td className="commit-message">
        {commit.message}
    </td>
); 
CommitMessage.propTypes = {
    commit: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const testFiles = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'src',
    type: 'folder',
    updated_at: '2016-07-11 21:24:00',
    latestCommit: {
        message: 'Initial commit'
    }
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'tests',
    type: 'folder',
    updated_at: "2016-07-11 21:24:00",
    latestCommit: {
        message: 'Initial commit'
    }
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'README',
    type: 'file',
    updated_at: "2016-07-18 21:24:00",
    latestCommit: {
        message: 'Added a readme'
    }
},
];
```

The error points to where I to the CommitMessage component where I declare {commit.message}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably has something to do with this

```
const FileListItem = ({ file }) => (
    <tr className="file-list-item">
        <FileName file={file} />
        <CommitMessage
            commit={file.lastestCommit} />
    </tr>
);
```

lastestCommit, looks like a typo.